# How can I get firstName and lastName from apple sign in using IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, apple-sign-in

I am using IdentityServer4 to authenticate users in my application.

I've added apple as an external provider. Added scopes: email and name. Apple says, that they send user information not in id_token, but in separate model:

```js
user: { "name": { "firstName": string, "lastName": string }, "email": string }
```

Looks like email added in id_token too, and I am actually getting it in External controller from external user claims. But there is not name, or firstName, or lastName. How can I get this information using IdentityServer4?

[image]

Comment: how did u add apple? did u use provider on https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers?

Comment: @nahidf, i've added a picture with adding provider.

Comment: added an answer, its easier to read there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract these props from user object returned from apple, like what is done on https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple/AppleAuthenticationHandler.cs#L167
If you use `.AddApple` extension on [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple/) would be easier as the code already there. Checkout [docs](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/docs/sign-in-with-apple.md) for detailed instruction.